# What is the difference between Geothermal HVAC and Heat pump?

Tags: renewables, air-conditioning, geothermal

What is the difference between these two renewable energy air conditioning systems?

Comment: Some context to your particular situation might (or might not) be useful... if you'd like to edit that into your question, you may get a more useful response.

Comment: related: http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/4400/48

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I think i can understand some concepts about it, ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ground-source heat pump is not a form of geothermal energy at all.

Geothermal:

1. energy source is underground natural nuclear reactions;
2. source temperature is over 50°C;
3. Energy is extracted with passive heat exchangers.

Ground-source heat pumps:

1. energy source is solar radiation;
2. source temperature is about the same as annual average air temperature;
3. Energy is extracted using active technology, compressing and expanding fluids to lift the temperatures to something useful.

Comment: I see. Ground-source heat pump is not exactly a form of Geothermal energy

Comment: Ground-source heat pump is not a form of geothermal energy at all.

Comment: So the geothermal heat pump refers to geothermal energy?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a "geothermal heat pump"?

Comment: I just read an article from here(http://energy.gov/energysaver/heat-pump-systems) in paragraph 4, it says that geothermal heat pump includes ground source heat pump and water source heat pump, is that true?

Comment: Oh, I see. That is weird.